# Ltib Installation Woes

Tags: linux, debian, rpm

I'm trying to get ltib installed , for installation of some packages that I need. 
I've gotten to the point of installation where I do

./ltib

and it gives me this error in the host_config.log

```
Build path taken because:no prebuilt rpm
Can't get: rpm-4.0.4.tar.gz at ./ltib line 851
Died at ./ltib line 2557
traceback:
    main::check_rpm_setup:2557
      main::host_checks:1541
        main:562

.... 
and then it says : 
    These packages failed to build:
      rpm-fs
Build failed
```

I have rpm on this installation of debian linux. I even downloaded rpm-4.0.4.tar.gz and placed it in the same directory as ./ltib

Has anyone encountered this error before?
Another question: Do I need internet connection for installation of ltib? (I downloaded the tar from the website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue has been solved, you need to change line 12 in rpm.spec file which is located /dist/lfs-5.1/rpm.

change

```
Source          : %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz"
```

to:

```
Source          : http://rpm.org/releases/historical/rpm-4.0.x/rpm-4.0.4.tar.gz
```

i think some files are missing on bitshrine.org server. You can apply same solution for other missing files.